# LS - sort by date, display only file name

Tags: unix, ls

I'm trying to list some files, but I only want the file names, in order of file date. I've tried a few commands but they don't see to work.

I know that using this code I can list only the file names:

```
ls -f *
```

And I know that using this command I can list the files sorted by date:

```
ls -ltr *
```

So I have tried using this command to list the file names only, sorted by file date, but it doesn't sort by date:

```
ls -ltr -f *
```

That last command simply lists the file names, but sorted by file name, not date.

Any ideas how I can do this with a simple ls command?

FYI, once I get this working my ultimate goal is to only list the most recently created 10 file names, using something like this:

```
ls -ltr -f * | tail -10
```

Comment: what, doesn't `ls -tr -f *` work? Good luck.

Comment: No. `ls -tr -f *` does not work.

Comment: so based on the `man page` quote below, `-f` doesn't sort files. What about `ls -tr *` to sort and display the files by their date. Glad you found a solution.

Comment: Next time, please, ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following command:

```
ls -ltr | awk '{ print $9 }' | tail -n +2
```

It extracts the file names from the ls -ltr command.

Comment: This works perfect. Thanks! Still don't understand why `-ltr -f` doesn't work, but, at least this is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual for `ls`, the `-f` flag is used to,

```
       -f     do not sort, enable -aU, disable -ls --color
```

One way of extracting only files would be,

```
ls -p | grep -v /
```

The option `-p` is used to append a '/' to a directory name, we can `grep` for lines not containing a '/'.

To extract 10 most recently used files you could do the following

```
ls -ptr * | grep -v / | tail -10
```

Comment: That does not work. It shows the entire listing, not just the file names.

Comment: In that case you can drop the `-l` option. I've updated the answer to show the same.